# How to affect displacement textures using objects?

Tags: displacement

So, this is my set up.

[image]

I placed a UV sphere with a Subdivision Surface Modifier of 3 render and view subdivisions along with a displacement modifier holding a cloud texture which is controlled by an empty. Now, this is going to be placed in an animation where the shape of the sphere is going to be continuously changed using the empty throughout the animation.
I could keyframe the movement of the empty but that would be too tedious to keep track of and setting a "Follow Path" constraint to the empty -- after creating a Bezier Circle around the sphere -- results in failure.
Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parent the empty to an object or to three vertices of an object.

Comment: any object in the scene, or what?

Comment: Yea, so the empty follows the animated object. Or maybe I didnt understand your original question.

Comment: Or maybe what you are looking for is a never ending cycle? Like with animation curves?

Comment: Please give some steps as to *how* the user should do this.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a cyclic animation